# Could not load assembly, path could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am new to powershell scripting. I am trying to execute SSIS using powershell. But getting error at `Add-Type -AssemblyName`. Could not find the assembly. I have kept the dll in the same folder as powershell script. What can be the reason why not getting the dll read.

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" 
    $ssisApplication = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application" 

    ##With Pathname and FileName 
    $ssisPackagePath = "T:\Railroad Board Output Project1\SSISPackage.dtsx\" 
    $ssisPackage = $ssisApplication.LoadPackage($ssisPackagePath,$null) 
    $ssisPackage.Execute()
```

I am getting error while reading this reffered dll. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: can you post complete error message?

Comment: `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS")`

Comment: Will check and let you know

Comment: I didn't get error after doing that but got new error in next line as "New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.DTS.Runtime.Application]: 

verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly is probably not in the Global Assembly Cache. If you have the .dll in the same directory, you should use the `-Path` parameter instead of `-AssemblyName`.